# Como obter o IP do HOST através do domínio em PYTHON?

Tags: python, ip, host

Em PHP, para obter o `ip` de um determinado domínio, eu costumo utilizar a função `gethostbyname`.

Exemplo PHP:

```
gethostbyname('www.google.com'); //201.17.165.210
```

E em Python? Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5):

Na realidade em python é quase isso:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com') # 216.58.211.196
```